# How to get Message object from MessageService object in Telethon

Tags: telegram, telethon

I'm getting `TypeError: 'MessageService' object is not iterable`

Fist I'm saving last 10 messages from a channel using `iter_messages` `client` method which returns `telethon.sync._SyncGen` generator object.
Then I'm iterating over this generator and trying send each message (`msg`) to the user (`username`) through `client`'s `send_message` method which can take either `str` or telethon `Message` object as a message argument.

However my `msg` object here is not an instance of the `Message` class but `MessageService` class (https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/constructors/message_service.html) and I assume this is the reason I'm getting the error.

```
message_objects = client.iter_messages(channel_name, limit=10)

for msg in message_objects:
    client.send_message(username, msg)
```

My question is how can get `Message` objects instead of `MessageService` in order to avoid the error and make the `client.send_message()` work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MessageService` objects are messages by Telegram e.g. "somebody joined this group" or "channel photo changed". `iter_messages` returns these messages along with other messages but you cannot send these messages. As you can see in the documentation you linked yourself, there is no real message inside a `MessageService` object. There is only a `MessageAction`.

You can skip this type of messages in your loop my checking their `type()` or by `hasattr(msg, 'message')`. Normal messages have `message` field which is the text you want to send. If you want to `send_message` (not forward), I think your code should be changed to:

```
client.send_message(username, getattr(msg, 'message', '...'))
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.
And if I need to send or forward these messages to a private channel, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: For private channels, you should instantiate an `InputChannel` object manually. This is what telethon does under the hood for public channels when you provide `@username`. 
`InputChannel` has 2 mandatory arguments: `id` and `access_hash`. You may call `GetAllChatsRequest` to get a full list of all chats of your account and find the specific private channel among them.

Comment: A note for anyone coming across this answer in the future: `MessageService` objects now have a message attribute (probably from Telethon and not Telegram), so instead you'll want to check `msg.message is not None` or stick with the type check.